# Idiomatic way to create static iterable collection of named structs?

Tags: data-structures, rust

What is the idiomatic way to create static iterable collection of named structs? I have `n` instances of a struct, where `n` is known at compile time and is less than 20. I would like to be able to iterate over all the entries and also be able to refer to each entry by a name instead of an index. All the data is known at compile time.

I could use an array or enum, along with hand written constants which map the labels to indexes; but this seems finicky.

```
fn common_behaviour(x: f64) {
   print!("{}", x);
}

const ADD: usize = 0;
const SUBTRACT: usize = 1;

fn main () {
    let mut foos: [f64; 2] = [0.0; 2];
    foos[ADD] = 4.0;
    foos[SUBTRACT] = 2.0;

    for foo in &foos {
       common_behaviour(*foo);
    }
    foos[ADD] += 1.0;
    foos[SUBTRACT] -= 1.0;
}
```

Alternatively, I could just pay the performance cost and use a HashMap as the hashing overhead might not actually matter that much, but this seems suboptimal as well.

Perhaps, I could refactor my code to use function pointers instead special casing the different special cases.

```
fn common_behaviour(x: f64) {
   print!("{}", x);
}

fn add(x: f64) -> f64 {
    x + 1.0
}

fn subtract(x: f64) -> f64 {
    x - 1.0
}

struct Foo {
   data: f64,
   special: fn(f64) -> f64
}

impl Foo {
    fn new(data: f64, special: fn(f64) -> f64) -> Foo {
        Foo { data, special }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut foos = [Foo::new(4.0, add), Foo::new(2.0, subtract)];

    for foo in &mut foos {
       common_behaviour(foo.data);
       foo.data = (foo.special)(foo.data);
    }
}
```

What is most idiomatic way to handle this situation?

Comment: Check out [rust-phf](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-phf) for maps generated at compile time.

Comment: This question could benefit from a code sample, showing what you have and how you use it; I have no idea what to make of the "function pointers" comment, it seems unrelated to the issue... which makes me think I didn't understand the issue to start with.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Code samples added. If you need more clarification, I am happy to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at:

```
fn main() {
    let mut foos = [Foo::new(4.0, add), Foo::new(2.0, subtract)];

    for foo in &mut foos {
       common_behaviour(foo.data);
       foo.data = (foo.special)(foo.data);
    }
}
```

I see a [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) struggling to emerge, and Rust is *great* at expressing this pattern, thanks to `enum`:

```
enum Foo {
    Add(f64),
    Sub(f64),
}

impl Foo {
    fn apply(&mut self) {
        match self {
            Foo::Add(x) => {
                Self::common(*x);
                *x += 1.0;
            },
            Foo::Sub(x) => {
                Self::common(*x);
                *x -= 1.0;
            },
        }
    }

    fn common(x: f64) {
        print!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

And your example becomes:

```
fn main() {
    let mut foos = [Foo::Add(4.0), Foo::Sub(2.0)];

    for foo in &mut foos {
       foo.apply();
    }
}
```